# Azure: connecting to a Windows VM from Linux

Tags: windows, azure

I using Azure to create Windows VM. I am able to create VMs, I am able to see that the port 3389 is open but I am unable to connect using `rdesktop`.

```
$ rdesktop 40.xx.xx.xx
ERROR: recv: Connection reset by peer
```

The server was created with the following URN:

```
MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2012-R2-Datacenter:4.0.20150916
```

Any idea how to connect to a windows server in azure after you have created the VM ?

**EDIT:**
All installations must be performed completely automated and I am currently using xplat to create the VM:

```
azure vm quick-create testrgcentral testVM westus Windows MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2012-R2-Datacenter:4.0.20150916 username mysafepassword
```

I can confirm that the port is open by scanning it with nmap

```
nmap 40.xxx.xxx.xxx -Pn
```

Comment: well, first you need to ensure that this VM is indeed running, if it is indeed, can you rather download the RDP file from the Azure console itself, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/

Comment: How are you checking that your RDP port is open, are you doing telnet ?

Comment: Also when you made the VM did you made it from the gallery template, because if not made from gallery template the RDP Port may be changed by the Azure

Comment: @BrijRajSingh I can confirm that the port is open with Telnet.

Comment: did you checked the public port, you can contact me on my twitter account @brijrajsingh we can fix this issue, one on one. I work for Microsoft

Comment: @BrijRajSingh thanks so much for your offer !!! However this time I have been able to work out a solution. While the command `rdesktop` did not work, the command `remmina` did the job. Now I am able to connect!

Answer (score 0):

If you have made your VM by using "Quick Create" option, you won't have port 3389 as your remote desktop endpoint from security point of view. go to "virtual Machines", select your VM, "EndPoints" -Remote Desktop - Port listed here as "Public Port" will be the port at which the RDP should be working, this port is mapped to the private port 3389 (which is the usual RDP Port)